# What is the proper way to update / create list collection data togehter along wih other field in firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I have this 2 model class this is my code

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'friends_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class FriendsModel {
  String name;
  String title;
  String? desc;

  FriendsModel(
      {required this.name,
      required this.title,
      this.desc});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FriendsModelToJson(this);

  factory FriendsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) =>
      _$FriendsModelFromJson(map);
}
```

and then

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'dpct_model.g.dart';
@JsonSerializable()

class DpctModel {
  String fullName;
  List<FriendsModel> myFriends;

 DpctModel(
      {required this.fullName,
      List<FriendsModel>? friendsList,

      }):     friendsList = friendsList ?? <FriendsModel>[],

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DpctModelToJson(this);

  factory DpctModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) =>
      _$DpctModelFromJson(map);
}
```

Now I want to save this into Cloud Firestore Database

so the data will  look like this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How / What is the proper way to save this into it ?

this is part of my code

```
final CollectionReference<DpctModel> _dpctCollectionReference =
      CloudFirestoreService.myFirestore
          .collection('dpct')
          .withConverter<DpctModel>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) =>
                DpctModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
          );
```

I use this

```
 Future create(DpctModel model) async {

    for (var element in model.friendsList) {
      Map<String, dynamic> value = element.toJson();
      _dpctCollectionReference
          .doc(model.nrp)
          .collection('friends')
          .add(value);
    }

}
```

it add a record into Firestore but how to add together other non collection field ?

Because i try

```
await _dpctCollectionReference.doc(model.nrp).set(model);
```

but it return me an error

also the add collection method keep adding the same record

any suggestion, would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1):

I am resolving this issue by myself, it because of Json nested class mapping at my model and i didn't set it explisit to json

so this code should work fine, and i only need to set @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true) at my DpctModel class

```
  Future create(DpctModel model) async {
    await _dpctCollectionReference.doc(model.nrp).set(model);

  }
```

and at My Model class

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
```